# How to animate using jqwicket?

Tags: jquery, wicket, jquery-animate

I am new to jqwicket. Basically I wanted to know how to add animation to a div using jqwicket.

It is easy to do this by using just html and jquery:

----- jquery part-----------

```
 $('#play').click(function()
{$('#testDIV').animate({top:'300', left:'10', height:'toggle',  
width:'toggle'},1000);}); $('#back').click(function() 
{$('#testDIV').animate({top:'40', left:'300', height:'toggle', width:'toggle'},1000);});
```

----- HTML part------------------------------

```
<div id="play">
  play
</div>
<div id="back">
  back
</div>
<div id="testDIV" style="position:absolute;float:right;clear:left;top:40px; left: 300px; background-color:red; height:50px;width:50px;" />
```

---

Now I want to translate the above jquery code to jqwicket code. It is the animation part that I don't understand.
In the java code I put this:

```
add(new JQBehavior(S.id("play").to$().click(JQuery.$f(S.id("testDIV").to$().animate(??????)))));
```

As you can see the animation part is filled with ? characters.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   add(new JQBehavior(
            S.id("play").to$().click(JQuery.$f(
                S.id("testDIV").to$().animate(JQOptions.valueOf("top:'300', left:'10', height:'toggle', " +
                        "width:'toggle'"), JQLiteral._raw(1000))
            )),
            S.id("back").to$().click(JQuery.$f(
                S.id("testDIV").to$().animate(JQOptions.valueOf("top:'40', left:'300', height:'toggle', " +
                        "width:'toggle'"), JQLiteral._raw(1000))
            ))

    ));
```